# rsync windows active directory deployment

Tags: windows, active-directory, rsync

Is there any tool that let me do a massive rsync installation through Active Directory for windows machines??,

I was searching but i do not find anything... until now. I am looking for something like this Zoolz tool..

http://wiki.zoolz.com/deploying-zoolz-to-domain-users-via-active-directory/

Comment: More info please - what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Yes, you can do large-scale software installations via group policies.

Comment: I am working with rsync.net, my company want to work with Rsync or Zoolz.... Zoolz have integration with the active directory and i want to do this with rsync...

Make a deployment on the computers of the active directory, computers of the domain... Install rsync client in all the computers, pre-configured with the route where is gonna to sync..

Comment: jlehtinen I will check that and try to do it, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As jlehtinen says above, Active Directory Group Policy Objects (GPOs) can be used to push software out to selected AD clients.  It's not massively difficult, but relies on the software install to be packaged in an MSI format.  This isn't normally an issue.  However, the post-install configuration also needs to be carried out.  There are two options here - MST (Master Transform) files, which are rolled into the MSI deployment at install time, or - and this is likely to be the easier option - use Group Policy preferences, which let you cleanly apply registry changes, put XML/INI/CFG files in place, Etc., Etc.

Back to AD software deployment - there's some good MS documents out there.  A starting point being http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/816102.

A distribution point, BTW, is simply just a file share that can be accessed by "authenticated users".  The Group Policy Object (GPO) itself can be targeted using security filtering - basically, you can target a given PC or user.  I'd recommend deploying the software based on computer name, and define the settings in the "Computer Configuration" part of the GPO.

Comment: Excelent, this solve my doubt, thanks a lot, i will try it.